# ehcache spring method cache unless doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache, spring-annotations

In my project (Java Spring 3.2) I have a method decorated with the `@Cacheable` annotation and I'm using ehcache.

The cache works fine except when the decorated code throws an exception

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "fooById", key = "'idFoo ' + #idFoo"  , unless="#result == null")
public Foo getFooById(Integer idFoo, boolean valueA,
        boolean valueB) { 

    try{
          //private method that call a web service
           Foo theFoo = getFoo(fooById); 
            return foo;
     }
    catch(Exception e){ 
          return null;
    }
}
```

As I read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775379/4341748 I'm expecting that the decorated method is executed for the next call with the same idFoo.
I cannot figure out why this not happen.

Another problem that i noticed is that the second call doesn't return anything from the cache and the `LOG.debug` is not executed

```
private void method(Integer id){
    Foo myFoo = fooService.getFooById(id, false, false);
         
    LOG.debug("foo received from cache or web services:" + foo.getName());
}
```

Again the cache expires well when the web service return a correct value.
Instead the cache is still blocked and not expire when the web service fail !!

Here is my configuration

## ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
     name="mySharedCache"
     updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect"
     maxBytesLocalHeap="100M"
     dynamicConfig="false">
<diskStore path="javax.servlet.context.tempdir"/>
<defaultCache eternal="false"
              timeToIdleSeconds="120"
              timeToLiveSeconds="120"
              overflowToDisk="false"
              diskPersistent="false"
              diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120">
</defaultCache> 
<cache
    name="getFooById"
    eternal="false"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    diskPersistent="false"
    timeToLiveSeconds="120">
 <cacheDecoratorFactory class="it.solinfo.leonardo.sintesi.utils.BlockingCacheDecoratorFactory" />
</cache>
```

## applicationContext.xml

```
    <beans>
       <cache:annotation-driven />
       <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache"/>
       <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:shared="true"/>
    </beans>
```

Comment: Finally i solved. 
The problem was the
 <cacheDecoratorFactory class="it.solinfo.leonardo.sintesi.utils.BlockingCacheDecoratorFactory" />