# @Cacheable conditional caching on request fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have used spring @Cacheable for caching as shown below:

```
@Cacheable
public Response mycall(Request request)
```

Now I want this method call to be cached only if request.getId()!=3, where `getId()`
is a public getter method in Request class.

I have seen code wherein people have specified `unless` condition in `@Cacheable`, but I have seen conditions being specified only on Response of the method and not on Request. Reference: [How do I tell Spring cache not to cache null value in @Cacheable annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113725/how-do-i-tell-spring-cache-not-to-cache-null-value-in-cacheable-annotation)

Is there any way to achieve the same with condition being specified on a field of the request

Comment: Don't you want something like `unless="#request.id == 3"` ?  It looks like parameters are available by name, and result as the name "#result", in the unless expression ...

Comment: i tried it , not working

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the condition attribute?

```
//It will cache only if the actor's age is more than 20. Here actor is the input parameter.
@Cacheable(value="movies", key="#actor.name", condition="#actor.age > 20")
public List<movie> getMovies(Actor actor) ...
```

See [ttps://www.codelooru.com/2017/03/spring-cache-part-3-conditional-cache.html](https://www.codelooru.com/2017/03/spring-cache-part-3-conditional-cache.html)